# Why is my while loop not working? Text-based adventure game

Tags: python

I'm doing my first project with Python and I was trying to do it without help, but I don't understand why is this not working.

I want to ask the user their age. If the user is older than 15, then he/she can play; if they're younger than 16 then I want to ask again for the age until the user says they're older than 15.

It works for when the user is less than 16, but if I type, say, 18, it still asks again.

```
while True:

    age = int(input('Please introduce your age: '))
    if age >= 15:
        character_info['age'] = age
        print('You are old enough to play')
    elif age <= 16:
        print('You are not old enough to play. Try again')
    age = int(input('Please introduce your age: '))
    continue
```

Comment: The loop has no way to exit. You'll need to either add a loop condition or insert a `break` statement somewhere.

Comment: 1. `break` not `continue` 2. check the conditions again for age brackets. GOod Luck!

Comment: You haven't told your program to do different things in each situation. Also, text-based adventures are a generally poor option for beginner programming projects, as you end up writing a lot of text but not doing much programming. I recommend puzzle or card games, like hangman, tic-tac-toe, Simon, Mastermind, blackjack, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break when the correct condition is met.

The correct logic is as follows

while True:

```
age = int(input('Please introduce your age: '))
if age >= 15:
    character_info['age'] = age
    print('You are old enough to play')
    break
elif age <= 16:
    print('You are not old enough to play. Try again')
```